# Property 'errors' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: angular

How can I fix this error? It seems to go away if I make the variable null but then it just creates another similar error.

> Property 'errors' does not exist on type 'string'.

All I want is to use the Angular Validator and `ngClass`to add a conventional class to my form-group, so I can use it on it's children with `ng-invalid`, `ng-touched` etc. The `*ngIf` is also not working. I'm assuming it is related.

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="aervform" id="aervform" #aervForm="ngForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <!-- [ngClass]="{
        'is-invalid': 
          aervform.get('membersName').errors 
          && (
            aervform.get('membersName').touched
            || 
            aervform.get('membersName').dirty
          )
      }" -->
      <div 
        class="form-group mb-2" 
        [ngClass]="{
          'is-invalid': 
            membersName.errors 
            && (
              membersName.touched 
              || 
              membersName.dirty
            ), 
          'is-valid':membersName.valid
        }">
        <label for="membersName" class="form-label">Member's Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="membersName"
          [(ngModel)]="membersName"
          formControlName="membersName"
          class="form-control"
          id="membersName"
          required
        />
        <span>Is it touched?: </span>{{this.aervform.controls.membersName.touched}}<br/>
        <span>Is it dirty?: </span>{{this.aervform.controls.membersName.dirty}}<br/>
        <span>Is it valid?: </span>{{this.aervform.controls.membersName.valid}}<br/>

        <div 
          class="is-invalid" 
          *ngIf="membersName.errors && (membersName.touched || membersName.dirty)">
          Field is required.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>      
</form>
```

Component

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  aervform: FormGroup;

  membersName: string = "";

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.aervform = this.fb.group({
      membersName: ["", [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
}
```

Here is a [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jeykke?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), Thanks

Comment: In second `form-group` you refer to this `membersName: string = "";` which is a string not an object therefore this will fail `membersName.errors`. To make things more complex the name `membersName` is used as a form field and as a field in component.

Comment: @robert yes...so how do I refer to a string? It is a string after all. Every tutorial I've seen sets it up this way

Comment: You cannot. string is string not a FormControl. Can you share the links to tutorials? With this `membersName: ["", [Validators.required]]` line you create a [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl)

Comment: @robert https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPuXl1DS1vU&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWNJaDgh0mfae_9xoQ4E_Zj&index=9

Comment: at timestamp 10:42 you can see the ts file. instead of membersName it is fullName I belelive. but that's just a name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app.module you need to import the correct Module

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
```

then on input field just use

```
formControlName="membersName"
```

to access a field inside a FormGroup (to display error messages) you need the full path. Not just a field name as in `formControlName`

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iidjjb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue that you use the `membersName` variable in your template. It's a string and does not relate to the `FormGroup` entity. There is no `errors` property inside the `membersName` variable because it's a string, not an object.

To properly access the `errors` property, you need to use `aervform.get('membersName')` instead of `membersName` inside your template.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bheg2e?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

@LOTUSMS I made couple of changes to your stckbliz example and made it working.

Will try to paste it here.

app.module.ts

```
imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
```

app.component.ts

```
membersName: FormControl = new FormControl("");
```

app.component.html

```
  <input
          type="text"
          name="membersName"
          formControlName="membersName"
          class="form-control"
          id="membersName"
          required
        />
        <span>Is it touched?: </span>{{aervform.controls.membersName.touched}}<br/>
        <span>Is it dirty?: </span>{{aervform.controls.membersName.dirty}}<br/>
        <span>Is it va
```